# How can I have a parentVC observe when one of its child subviews(collectionview) is being scrolled?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to emulate Apple's weather app animation where when you scroll, the top header collapses and remains as a condensed sticky cell. I am attempting to do this with all of the UI being done programmatically and without storyboards.

The two ways I've thought of implementing this each have an issue I have not been able to solve.

My initial attempt was having a containerVC contain a UIView (as a header) and a UICollectionViewController. The issue is that The containerVC cannot access the UICollectionViews scrollViewDidScroll() which I would use to calculate and adjsut the size of the UIView. I could make the containerVC the collectionViews delegate but I wanted to avoid that to keep my logic separated. I also tried using Key Value observers but I could not figure out how to make it work.

My second attempt was to use a UICollectionReusableView as a header cell, that way there is no container view, just a single collectionViewController. The issue here is I can't figure out how to dynamically resize the headercell. The header size is currently being returned from referenceSizeForHeaderInSection and I have been unable to find another way of updating this.

Is there a better way to be going about this? Or an easier solution to the issues described that I haven't tried yet?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a forum, it's a Q&A site, as was made clear to you when you joined. Do not edit the title of your question to add "tags", especially tags like [solved]. Do not edit your question to insert your solution. Instead, write an answer of your own, although that would not apply in this case. Simply accepting an answer was enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own delegates:

```
protocol ParentDelegate: class {
    func childDidScroll()
}

extension ParentViewController: ParentDelegate {
    func childDidScroll() {
        print("My child controller did scroll")
    }
}
```

Create a `delegate` variable in the class that you want to call it:

```
weak var delegate: ParentDelegate?
```

Set it to your parent ViewController:

```
delegate = parentVC
```

then inside your child scroll method you call it:

```
delegate?.childDidScroll()
```